# firebase auth sdk login user with email and passworrd

Tags: python, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm using firebase auth sdk for an application and I'd like to log the user in. I cannot understand how it works.

To create a new user I run this code:

```
from firebase_admin import auth

....

def create_user(email, password):
    user = auth.create_user(email=email, password=password)
    return user
```

Now I'd like to log the user in. The auth doesn't have a method to log in the user. It has a auth.get_user_by_email(email) or some other methods to get user(s), but it has no method to check user's password. My application (API) gets email and password and I need to return the user if the email and password match.

How do I do this using the firebase sdk?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging into Firebase happens on the client, not on the server. So the Firebase Admin SDKs don't have a method to sign the user in, but all client-side SDKs (such as the [Web/JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth)) have methods to sign in the user.

If you want to sign in a specific user from your Python code, you can call the REST API, or use a library like Pyrebase that wraps this REST API: https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#authentication.

Comment: Thanks for help. Can you, please, tell me how do I check, after authentication, if the token wasn't revoked? I'm using python, as backend to manage user's session.

Comment: To check the validity of the ID token, you'll want to use the Admin SDK (as this is a trusted operation). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens